# Amazon AWS boto S3 Changing file contents

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3, mp4

[image]Trying to upload a mp4 file to an Amazon S3 server, it uploads. When downloading it's exactly the same size but bytes 42, 43, 44 changes.

Looking up that's mdat. http://www.file-recovery.com/mp4-signature-format.htm

I tried changing mime types to various ones and also even changed extension to exe. No luck..

When trying to playback the video it does not work.

I'm using the boto python framework to do this.

Any ideas?

```
 # Uploads a file to a bucket
def upload_file_to_bucket(self, file_path_on_disk, file_name_in_bucket, bucket_name):
    self.remove_file_from_bucket(file_name_in_bucket, bucket_name)
    if os.path.exists(file_path_on_disk):
        print "Uploading " + file_path_on_disk + " to " + file_name_in_bucket + " in bucket " + bucket_name
        bucket = self.get_connection().get_bucket(bucket_name)
        k = bucket.new_key(file_name_in_bucket)
        k.set_contents_from_filename(file_path_on_disk, headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream', 'Body' : 'data'}) # {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment', 'Content-Type' : 'video/mp4'}) headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream'}
        k.set_acl('public-read')
        print "Uploaded file to amazon server " + bucket_name 
    else:
        print "File does not exist so cannot upload " + file_path_on_disk
```

Edit:
Looking further. seems there is a lot more corruption than that. Dodgy Load balancer?

Is it possible there a way to ensure the file is uploaded correctly? At the moment, it's always wrong.

EDIT:

This was due to the file not being fully written before being uploaded if anyone encounters this.

Comment: S3 supports an optional upload header, `Content-MD5`, which should be set to the base64-encoded binary MD5 of the uploaded object.  If boto doesn't automatically do that for you, the developers should have their keyboard privileges revoked... because S3 will reject a corrupted upload if this hash doesn't match on an upload -- that's how you guarantee upload integrity.  Secondarily, when uploading an object the etag is set to the hex-encoded md5 (or the output a slightly more complex algorithm for multipart uploads).  Does this help?  If the etag matches the md5, it's stored correctly in S3.

Answer (score 1):

The right content type is `video/mp4` you can set it like this from both

```
data = open('file.mp4', 'rb')
bucket.put_object(Key='file.mp4', Body=data, ContentType='video/mp4')
```

make sure the type is set correctly after upload in the s3, navigate to your file and check the properties / Metadata. Note that `video/mp4` is not in the drop down list of available content type from AWS but you can force it by writing the content you want

Comment: Tried that, but did not work. Exactly the same issue

Comment: Didn't try "Body=data"

Comment: update your code how you push your file using python code - try to upload the file directly from your browser and set the content type do you have the same issue ?

Comment: Using dragon disk and setting no meta data it worked fine.

Comment: boto does not change the content of your file .. post your code how you currently run the upload